freertos linking problems to a z80 device
I'm using the Z88DK C compiler to control my Z80 CPU. While trying to link the FreeRTOS library to my project, I've run into some issues. I'm configuring the Z80 with EEPROM from 0 to FFF and RAM from 1000 to FFF7, reserving 8 bytes for other usage. The bin file I'm generating will be used in a Proteus 8 simulation on the EEPROM. However, I'm having trouble with linking the FreeRTOS library
well here's the c file (named test.c) :
#include "include/FreeRTOS.h"

#include "include/sdcc/task.h"   


    int main(void) {

                    unsigned short* p1 = (unsigned short*)0xFFF7;
                    unsigned short* tracker1 = (unsigned short*)0xFFF8;
                    unsigned short* tracker2 = (unsigned short*)0xFFF9;
                    unsigned short* tracker3 = (unsigned short*)0xFFFA;
                    unsigned short* tracker4 = (unsigned short*)0xFFFB;
                    *p1 |= 0x01;

        vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));  // Delay for 1000 milliseconds


                    *tracker1 = ((*p1 >> 4) & 0x01)? 0x02:0x01;
                    
                    *tracker2 = ((*p1 >> 5) & 0x01)? 0x02:0x01;
                    *tracker3 = ((*p1 >> 6) & 0x01)? 0x02:0x01;

        for(;;); }

As I mentioned, I'm using the Z88DK compiler with this command to generate the bin file:
zcc +z80 -O3 -clib=classic test.c -o test.bin -crt0=crt0.asm -m -compiler=sdcc
with ctr0.asm :
    EXTERN    _main
    defc    CRT_ORG_CODE = 0x0000
    org     CRT_ORG_CODE
start:
    jp      _main


initially i had a error message :
test.c:19: error 20: Undefined identifier 'configTICK_RATE_HZ'
so i added this line of code to FreeRTOSConfig.h:
#define configTICK_RATE_HZ 1000
then i had this error:
test.c:321: error: undefined symbol: _vTaskDelay
  ^---- _vTaskDelay
The header files I'm using are represented within the GitHub repo. hereI wanted to use vTaskDelay but couldn't.

Including the header is not enough to build a program. You need the implementation, too. Does this answer your question? What's the difference between a header file and a library?

Also HERE you won't get away with this stripped down crt0.asm. You'll need to at least set up some stack in your RAM; also if you manage to get FreeRTOS compiled in, you'll certainly need BSS placed in RAM (i.e. global statics in C - surely FreeRTOS got some of those it'll need to use). Probably DATA also (i.e. initialized global statics) which need both RAM area, ROM area AND some code to copy one into another. In other words, give up this crt0.asm stub and try to get C library proper working in your setup (Classic Homebrew doc)

Also also... Assuming you did all that, got your application compiled and C library doing its initialization thing... You now need to make FreeRTOS work. Particularly, I don't think you can just call vTaskDelay outside of, you know, task. You need to create that task and start FreeRTOS scheduler. And then you need a way for FreeRTOS to track time and act on it, which implies having a timer interrupt hooked into FreeRTOS tick handler.

Thank you once more for clarifying things for me.
